# No taskbar entry for QDialog using console application

Tags: qt, dialog, focus, taskbar

I am writing a Qt Console Application using Qt Creator 4.6.0 in Linux. I would like to show a QDialog but I do not want it to

1. show an entry on taskbar, and
2. steal focus from other windows.

How can I do this?

I found kind of similar question, but the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240764/3179989) does not work for me as it seems that I can't use `this` in a console application.

Here is what I have so far which shows the dialog but it neither hides it from taskbar, nor prevents it from stealing the focus:

```
    QDialog splash;
    QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
    splash.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    splash.setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
    laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
    lblText->setText(QString::fromStdString("test"));
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &splash, SLOT(close()));
    splash.exec();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set parameters with `exec()` seems *contradicting* and won't prevent showing a *blocking* modal dialog that steals focus, if you just `show()` the dialog instead of `exec()`, other settings work. below code was tested on `Debian Ubuntu 17.10`, and achieves desired results

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //
    QDialog splash;
    QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
    splash.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    splash.setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
    laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
    lblText->setText(QString::fromStdString("test"));
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, &splash, SLOT(close()));
    splash.show();
    //
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Update:**

If the code should work before or without a main event loop (before `a.exec()` is called or even without at all calling `a.exec()`), you need to enter an event loop to host your dialog, this can be repeated for each additional code separately; eventually you might opt to `return` any `int` value depending on your code.

```
#include <QEventLoop>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //
    QDialog splash;
    QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
    splash.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    splash.setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
    laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
    lblText->setText(QString::fromStdString("test"));
    QEventLoop ev;
    splash.show();
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, &ev, &QEventLoop::quit);
    ev.exec();
    //
    // More code .. more event loops
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it does not work without `return a.exec();` which is not good as I need it to display right after `splash.show();` or `splash.exec();` as there are lots of other code after displaying the splash dialog. Also It still shows the taskbar entry.

Comment: Ok, that was sample code, you can end with your own design, if you don't want to enter main event loop for example, see my update; But what is worrying is your lat sentence _Also It still shows the taskbar entry_ ... because in my Linux, it does not appear with the solution!

Comment: Thanks. It does not steal focus anymore, but it does still show up in taskbar. Any suggestion?

Comment: @NESHOM, whats your Linux, I use Ubuntu 17 and it works, thats essentially the case when you use `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool)` ..! whats your Qt version?

Comment: I am in Lubuntu using Qt Creator 4.5.2 Based on Qt 5.10.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit). Are you able to share your console application to try your exact application?

Comment: @NESHOM Nothing more than what I put in answer

Comment: @NESHOM, I think you want to put an image of how your taskbar looks when you run app